# Difference between tf.Module and tf.keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I know both `tf.Module` and `tf.keras.Model` are used for building custom models.
But what's the difference between both of them?
Which one should be used when becuase there usage looks similar as shown in tensorflow docs?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.Model` is an higher class to build your model. If you look the class tree, you will see the `tf.Module`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import inspect
```

```
>>> inspect.getclasstree(inspect.getmro(tf.keras.Model))
[(object, ()),
 [(keras.utils.version_utils.LayerVersionSelector, (object,)),
  [(keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,
    (tensorflow.python.module.module.Module,
     keras.utils.version_utils.LayerVersionSelector)),
   [(keras.engine.training.Model,
     (keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,
      keras.utils.version_utils.ModelVersionSelector))]],
  (keras.utils.version_utils.ModelVersionSelector, (object,)),
  [(keras.engine.training.Model,
    (keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,
     keras.utils.version_utils.ModelVersionSelector))],
  (tensorflow.python.trackable.base.Trackable, (object,)),
  [(tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable.AutoTrackable,
    (tensorflow.python.trackable.base.Trackable,)),
   [(tensorflow.python.module.module.Module,  # <- HERE
     (tensorflow.python.trackable.autotrackable.AutoTrackable,)),
    [(keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,
      (tensorflow.python.module.module.Module,
       keras.utils.version_utils.LayerVersionSelector)),
     [(keras.engine.training.Model,
       (keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,
        keras.utils.version_utils.ModelVersionSelector))]]]]]]
```

You can probably do the same thing but you will lose useful methods and I think you will find less community documentation using `tf.Module` (Opinion based)